# Date from SQL datebase to JCalander

Tags: string, date, jcalendar

I used http://toedter.com/ `jDateChooser` to get the date from user. But now I want to reset the selected date to the calendar from SQL database. This is the code I wrote to put selected date to database.

```
pst.setString(5, ((JTextField)datead.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

```
java.util.Date dateadx = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateadm);
```

Here `dateadm` is the String variable which you want to store as date in `JDateChooser`.

Then you can simply call

```
datead.setDate(dateadx)
```

to set the date.